# How to display the duplicate values in a tibble?

Tags: r, statistics

I have a tibble with name and year as two columns. I want to display the names which occur more than once in the tibble. How can I approach this?

Comment: u can use add_counts or filter after grouping with name'

Answer (score 0):

`duplicated` is the workhorse behind `unique`. You can use that one.

```
library(tidyverse)

mytibble <- tibble(name = c("B", "A", "A"), year = 2017:2019)

mytibble %>% 
  filter(duplicated(.$name))
```

Comment: I tried duplicated and then filter, but R complained that filter cannot be applied to an object of class "logical"

Comment: `filter` takes data as first argument like every key verb of the `dplyr` stack.